# Como muestro el resultado de otra tabla dependiendo el usuario en laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el HomeController:

```
public function index()
    {
      $sistema = DB::table('sistema as s')
                  ->join('users as u','s.id_sistema','u.id_sistema')
                  ->where('u.id_sistema','=',auth()->user()->id_sistema)
                  ->select('u.usuario','s.descripcion');

          return view('home',compact('sistema'));
    }
```

Me devuelve este error.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sistema/resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

Quiero devolver la informacion de otra tabla dependiendo el usuario logueado, por ejemplo si el id_usuario=1 (eso ya lo logro traer) el id_sistema es el que tenga en esa fila de ese usuario, como puedo hacer?

Esta es la vista

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    Esta en el Dashboard
                    y estos son los datos
                    {{ auth()->user()->id_sistema }}
                    {{ auth()->user()->id_usuario }}
                    {{ auth()->user()->usuario }}
                    {{ auth()->user()->password }}
                    {{ auth()->user()->contrasena }}

                    {{$sistema}}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Agrega el código de la vista por favor

Comment: ya lo agregue, espero sirva

Answer (score 2):

debes agregar un first() al final de la sentencia del ORM

```
$sistema = DB::table('sistema as s')
                  ->join('users as u','s.id_sistema','u.id_sistema')
                  ->where('u.id_sistema','=',auth()->user()->id_sistema)
                  ->select('u.usuario','s.descripcion')
                  ->first();
```

y luego debes imprimir las pripiedades en tu HTML debe hacer algo como

```
{{ $sistema->id_sistema }}
```

Comment: Gracias. me has ayudado

Comment: Excelente!!! es la idea...

Comment: de casualidad sabes como ir a un link dependiendo de una variable, por ejemplo:   con la solucion que me diste antes la tabla sistema tiene un campo que se llama url
      echo URL("/{$sistema->url}"); lo que quiero es ir a esa url sin dar click en ningun boton

Comment: asumiendo que estas usando laravel puedes hacerlo con el redirect del framework, alli puedes ver la documentacion https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirect

Comment: fijate que si lo intente hacer asi, per me sale un return con http://localhost:8000/URL_QUE_DESEO

Comment: estas usando laravel? o php puro?

Comment: estoy usando laravel 5.8

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98918/discussion-between-jean-carlos-garcia-and-mau-espana).